# How to get logged person's user_id from the database and match the user id session with the second table as the foreign key?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO useraccounts (name, email, taman, password) VALUES ('" . $_POST['name'] . "', '" . $_POST['email'] . "', '" . $_POST['taman'] . "','" . $_POST['passsword'] . "')";
if ($db->query($sql)) {
    $id = $db->insert_id;
    $query = "";
    $count = count($_POST['barang']);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO requestitem (barang, deskripsi, kategori, image, uID) VALUES ( '$barang', '$deskripsi', '$kategori','$newImageName', 
         '$id')";
    }
    if ($db->multi_query($query)) {
        echo
        "<script>
                 alert('Successfully Added!');
                 document.location.href = 'displayRequest.php';
                 </script>";
    } else {
        echo "Failed";
    }
} else {
    echo "Failed";
}
```

Here is my current code. I would like to seek for help on how can I fix this code in order to insert data in second table by using current user id session as its foreign key in that second table?

Answer (score -1):

First thing in this code:

```
for($i=0; $i<$count;$i++){
                $query = "INSERT INTO requestitem (barang, deskripsi, kategori, image, uID) VALUES ( '$barang', '$deskripsi', '$kategori','$newImageName', 
                '$id')";
                }
```

You maybe wanted to use .= instead of just =. And use ; at the end of sql query.

+be carefull with inserting user data to sql. Escape it to prevent SQL injections!

Comment: The code is the same as in OP. AND the escaping does not prevent SQL injection! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php